# Resolve Authentication problem JWT Bearer for .NET Core API

Tags: jwt, postman, asp.net-core-3.1, bearer-token

I use .NET Core 3.1 API and I would like to configure a JWT Bear Token.
I have configured a method which generates a token with a ValidateLifetime of one day.

Then, I put [authorize] on my usercontroller method and I tested all with Postman, by using my token and selecting "Bearer Token as Authorisation method "but I don't know why it doesn't work.

I filled out the token generated previously by my GenerateToken method, I tried to enter only the header part of the jwt token, the header/content/signature of the jwt token but it doesn't work.

Would someone have a video or tutorial explaining how to test the "Bear token" as authentication mode?

//example of generated token :
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9uYW1lIjoiYXJ0aHVyIiwiaHR0cDovL3NjaGVtYXMueG1sc29hcC5vcmcvd3MvMjAwNS8wNS9pZGVudGl0eS9jbGFpbXMvbmFtZWlkZW50aWZpZXIiOiIxIiwibmJmIjoiMTYxMDI5OTAzMyIsImV4cCI6IjE2MTAzODU0MzMiLCJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy5taWNyb3NvZnQuY29tL3dzLzIwMDgvMDYvaWRlbnRpdHkvY2xhaW1zL3JvbGUiOiJBZG1pbiJ9.E9TnS62nv10gNH8U03OPhK_QrGLEotnS7yjHBvh4i0E

````
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>{
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name , UserNAME),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userId),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Nbf,new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now).ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString()),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Exp,new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)).ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString())
            };
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"));
            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                    new JwtHeader(
                        new SigningCredentials(
                            new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SECRET_KEY)),
                            SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256
                            )),
                        new JwtPayload(claims));
            var output = new
            {
                Accces_Token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
                UserName = UserNAME
            };
            return output;




        }
//this is my authentication services
 services.AddAuthentication(options => {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "jwtBearer";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "jwtBearer";
            }).AddJwtBearer("jwtBearer", jwtoptions => {
                jwtoptions.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    IssuerSigningKey = SIGNING_KEY,
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5) };
            });
//this is my IApplicationBuilder application configure : {
  app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();```}
````

Answer (score 1):

From the code of generating token, `SIGNING_KEY` is a string, but `IssuerSigningKey` is a type of `SecurityKey`. So in the configuration, it need to be changed.

```
jwtoptions.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SIGNING_KEY)),
               
            };
```

The way you tested token may be not correct. After generating the token, you put it in the request header. **Note the Bearer**.

[image]

Comment: this is my SIGNING_KEY , as you can see it is not a string  ```public static readonly SymmetricSecurityKey SIGNING_KEY = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SECRET_KEY));```

Comment: @MUTIJIMA, I test your code, it can work correctly, you could lost the Bearer which you can refer to the answer.